# Disallow node app from accessing global npm modules, or at least warn?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there any way to either (a) disallow a node application from `require`/`import`ing globally-installed npm modules, or (b) at least output a warning when a globally-installed module is used?

Reason being: I've repeatedly wound up in situations where a developer (myself included) incorporates a module in a node application but fails to add it to `package.json` because it happens to be globally installed on their machine, and therefore there's no error on the local machine; but upon deployment to a system that doesn't have that module installed globally, of course, it fails. Would be convenient to just ensure that all modules are in fact included in `package.json`.

Comment: Not sure about directly, but this is something that Continuous Integration (CI) passes can shake out.

Comment: if it's executables so how about using `./node_modules/.bin/` in scripts section of package.json?

Comment: Indeed, and we have that in place for most projects, but it'd be a nice convenience to make it easier to catch this sort of error before the pull request goes up.

Comment: I think You've to write `postinstall`, `precommit`, `prepush` (check `husky` module) scripts which will run through files and make sure that require, import statements use dependencies from package.json, otherwise `exit -1`   for that purpose check this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependency-tree

Comment: Why do you want to install globally at all? Is it possible to uninstall all global and now start using dev-dependencies (if not required by production system), or as dependencies (if required in prod machines).

Comment: @Prakhar he means that in app code there are import, require statements that use globally installed modules that not declared in package.json. so he wants to remind developers to declare that dependency in package.json automatically. as if You’ve done feature and You want to commit and push it, but configuration of app not allowing You to push potentially failing code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ESLint Way**

1) use [husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) module: `npm install husky --save-dev`

2) install eslint and it's deps (see package.json example below).

3) example package.json:

```
{
  "name": "shopping-cart-estimator-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ports/http.js",
    "eslint-check": "./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js .",
    "eslint-fix": "./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js . --fix",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha test --exit"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "mocha": "^7.1.2",
    "eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-config-import": "^0.13.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.15"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run eslint-check && npm test",
      "pre-push": "npm run eslint-check && npm test"
    }
  }
}
```

4) create `.eslintrc.js` file with [import/no-extraneous-dependencies](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-extraneous-dependencies.md) rule (it requires [eslint-plugin-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import), make sure it's in package.json):

```
module.exports = {
  "extends": "standard",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "semi": ["error", "always"],
    "no-unused-vars": 1,
    "spaced-comment": ["warn"],
    "no-trailing-spaces": ["warn"],
    "comma-dangle": ["error", {
      "arrays": "always",
      "objects": "always",
      "imports": "never",
      "exports": "never",
      "functions": "never"
    }],
    "space-before-function-paren": ["error", {
      "anonymous": "always",
      "named": "never",
      "asyncArrow": "always"
    }],
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {"packageDir": __dirname}],
  },
  "overrides": [{
    "files": ["spec/tests/*.js", "spec/tests/**/*.js"],
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-expressions": 0,
      "no-unused-vars": 1
    }
  }]
};
```

**"Custom Script way"**

1) use [husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) module: `npm install husky --save-dev`

2) add hook to pre-commit, pre-push in package.json:

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm test && node scripts/check-deps.js",
      "pre-push": "npm test && node scripts/check-deps.js"
    }
  }
```

3) install [dependency-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependency-tree): `npm i --save dependency-tree`

4) write `scripts/check-deps.js` script that will find external (non package.json) dependencies and if they exist will:

```
console.warn('Found external dependency'); 
process.exit(-1);
```

Comment: @DanM I've updated my answer, I think ESLint will solve Your problem, give it a try